# What are the possible causes?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

In Google Cloud Platform Cloud SQL, the following error log is generated every second. What are the possible causes?

Google App Engine has stopped, so I don't think it is the cause.

```
Aborted connection 1000 to db: ‘unconnected’ user: ‘user-name’ host: ‘localhost’ (Got an error reading communication packets)`
```

Comment: Can you please share with us some logs from App Engine? Are you only getting this logs from Cloud SQL or are you actually seeing connections issues?

Comment: As you can see in the [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues?hl#aborted-connection) this may be happening because your application is not terminating connections properly or network issues. Can this be related to your actual issue?